# Equations for geodesics of the plane in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, geodesic

I'm studying equations for geodesics of the plane in polar coordinates from the book "gravity by James hartle" and I am stuck at the last step which involves partial derivative of 3 variable.
The metric of the plane in polar coordinates $r$ and $Φ$ is :
$$
dS^2 = dr^2 + r^2dΦ^2
$$
A curve between two points $A$ and $B$ can be described parametrically by giving $r$ and $Φ$ as a function of a parameter $σ$ which varies between $σ=0$ at point $A$ and $σ=1$ at point $B$
distance between $A$ and $B$ is given by:
$$
\int_A^B dS = \int_A^B (dr^2 + r^2 dΦ^2)^{1/2}
                  = \int_0^1 {dσ} \left[ \left(\frac{dr}{dσ}^2\right) + r^2\left(\frac{dΦ}{dσ}\right)^2\right]^{1/2}
$$
Solve the above equation by Lagrangian and we will get :
$$
\frac d{dσ}\left(\frac1L\frac{dr}{dσ}\right) = \frac rL\left(\frac{dΦ}{dσ}\right)^2
\tag{1}
$$$$
\frac d{dσ}\left(\frac1L r^2 \frac{dΦ}{dσ}\right) = 0
\tag{2}
$$
Now writer says that the value of $L$ is just $dS/dσ$. Therefore, multiplying above equations by $dσ/dS$, the equations for geodesics using the distance $S$ as the parameter along the curve take the simple form
$$
\frac{d^2r}{ds^2} = r\left(\frac{dΦ}{dS}\right)^2
\tag{3}
$$$$
\frac d{dS}\left(r^2 \frac{dΦ}{dS}\right) = 0
\tag{4}
$$

Can somebody please explain how do we get equations 3 and 4 from 1 and 2 ?? I understand the rest of the calculation but facing difficulty how to deal with these mix partial derivatives.

Thanks

Comment: Formally, if $L = dS/d\sigma$, then $1/L = d\sigma/dS$ and the chain rule gives $$\frac{d}{dS} = \frac{d\sigma}{dS}\, \frac{d}{d\sigma} = \frac{1}{L}\, \frac{d}{d\sigma}.$$If you post an answer I'd be happy to upvote. (The small $s$ on the left side of (3) looks like a typo for $S$.)